# Save dark mode in php cookies

Tags: css

I worked on a simple little code for black mode

I would just like to store the theme for the user in cookies for x time

My Dark Theme in css :

```
body {
  padding: 0px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

.dark-mode .mainSection {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 600px;
  padding-top: 470px;
}
```

Html

```
  <div id="dark-mode">
    <li><font size="2">
      <a class="nav-link" onclick="myFunction()">Dark Mode</font
    </li>
  </div>
```

Javascript :

```
  function myFunction() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Simply set the cookie using javascript i.e [document.cookie](  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)  PHP will receive the cookie automatically the next time the client makes the request

Comment: A suggestion for you instead of using cookies use `localStorage` for saving dark/light mode preference.

Comment: Ok thank you very much i will look at the mozilla documentation and look at the local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the cookie using javascript, and the next time the client makes the request to server, the cookies will be send along with it. The below code should work

```
 function createCookie(name, value, timeInSeconds) {
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime()+(timeInSeconds*1000));
       var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    
       document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
 }

 function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function myFunction() {
      var element = document.body;
      const isDarkModeOn = element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
      createCookie("isDarkModeOn", isDarkMode.toString(), 60 * 60 * 24); // 1 day expiry date
}

window.onload = function () {
  const isDarkModeOn = getCookie("isDarkModeOn");
  if(isDarkModeOn === "true") document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
}
```

After that simply check the cookie in PHP,

```
<?php
 $isDarkModeOn = $_COOKIE["isDarkModeOn"] === "true";
 if($isDarkModeOn) {
   echo "Dark Mode is on";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, it works, the cookies store well but when I refresh the dark mode does not stay, is it normal?

Comment: @rosamaria My bad, was using a fixed value to set the dark mode (`"true"`). The code should work now

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, when I refresh the dark mode does not stay, I will try to see why, thank you

Comment: @rosamaria Ahh are you setting the element classList as `dark-mode` when the dark mode is set in cookies?

Comment: No I haven't defined it, sorry I'm starting out in php

Comment: @rosamaria It's alright, you don't need to do this in PHP. You can simply do that using javascript, I have updated the code above. Try it out

Comment: It works! you are a genius, thank you very much!
I edit the post! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, go ahead and mark this answer as correct if it's working for you.

Comment: it's good i updated the post, thanks for your help

Comment: Ahh, I see you are new to stackoverflow, to mark an answer as correct you have to click on the tick bar below the answer upvote section

Comment: When I click or to close the post? sorry

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you are saying, this I what I'm talking about. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwTL.png